# How to dynamically handle network_security_config.xml file incase of certificate expire? Without android app update?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-network-security-config

I have implemented certificate pinning in my Android app, now the question is going future if certificate got expired or if we renewed our certificate. In that case do we need to add the new certificate again and give another app update?

To avoid an app update, is there any way that we can just renew the certificate and continue with the same certificate without app update?

Comment: You cannot modify manifest entries or resources except by updating the app. "The use case is that I want to update certificate by without updating android app" -- we do not know what you mean by this, because your network security config XML is empty.

Comment: @CommonsWare If certificate expire then we need to update the app by updating valid certificate. Do we have any other option so that we can handle certificate upgrade without app update?

Comment: You might consider editing your question to include more of the `<network-security-config>` content and explain in detail what you are doing with the certificate.

Comment: I have a similar requirement for our development environments where the certs are changed frequently and I cannot have them hardcoded in the app. Please let me know if you were able to find any solution.